# Misunderstanding the Model-View-Projection matrix in OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, matrix

I am attempting to write a basic program in modern OpenGL using Python and pyglet.  I am able to place a simple triangle on the screen with different colors for each of the corners.  I am at the point where I am attempting to add the projection and view matrix so that I am able to move the "camera" around in 3D space, but it keeps black-screening when I add both matrices.  I can add the projection matrix and it works as expected. I can simply just add the view matrix, and it still shows the triangle.  However, when I multiply the view matrix and the projection matrix together it gives a black screen.

Since I am able to produce a colored triangle with the projection matrix, I *think* I can safely assume that all my OpenGL context is valid.  So, maybe I must have misunderstood the mathematics.

Here is a summary of my relevant code:

```
import pyrr

fov = 60
aspect_ratio = 800 / 600 #width / height
near_clip = 0.1
far_clip = 100

#create a perspective matrix
projection_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection(
fov,
aspect_ratio,
near_clip,
far_clip
)

view_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.creat_look_at(
pyrr.vector3.create(0, 0, 1), #camera position
pyrr.vector3.create(0, 0, 0), #camera target
pyrr.vector3.create(0, 1, 0)  #camera up vector
)

mvp_matrix = projection_matrix * view_matrix
```

From here, I translate the mvp_matrix into a c_types array that OpenGL can understand.  I don't think the code that does the translation is relevant since it works with just the projection matrix correctly.

Here are the matrices that pyrr is giving me:

```
Projection Matrix:
[[ 1.15470054  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          1.73205081  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.         -1.002002   -1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.         -0.2002002   0.        ]]

View Matrix:
[[1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [0.  0. -1.  1.]]

MVP Matrix:
[[ 1.15470054  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          1.73205081  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.         -1.002002   -0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.         -0.          0.        ]]
```

Any ideas on why just the projection matrix is able to show the triangle, but when I add in the view matrix it just shows black screens?

I've tried making the triangle really big on all the x, y, and z-axis, but still just a black screen. =/

Comment: The "MVP Matrix" seems to be not correct, because there is no translation along the z axis. That does not reflect the 1st parameter `pyrr.vector3.create(0, 0, 1)` (camera position).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing I've discovered that the pyrr module seems to be performing matrix multiplication strangely.  Pyrr is built on numpy however, so after using:

```
numpy.matmul(projection_matrix, view_matrix)
```

Then, it was able to create the MVP matrix correctly.